# Hi, does BigQuery support materialized views?

Tags: google-bigquery

Does BigQuery support materialized views? The documentation suggests to materialize the query output. does this mean materialized views are supported or is this as good as creating a new table with the query output?

Comment: I am not sure about this, but we kinda run ETL jobs every day to aggregate or process selected fields into a new or existing dim & agg tables.

Answer (score 8):

Materialized views are not (yet) supported in BigQuery at the time of this writing. You can [follow along with the relevant feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62244996), however. In the meantime, you need to create a table explicitly from a view, e.g.:

```
CREATE TABLE dataset.materialized_view AS
SELECT *
FROM dataset.view;
```

Answer (score 4):

BigQuery materialized views has been released as a beta.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/release-notes#April_08_2020

Answer (score 2):

If it is still relevant, maybe [materialized query results will do the work](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-costs#materialize_query_results_in_stages).

Answer (score 0):

In February 25, 2021 this feature has gone GA:
https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/bigquery-materialized-views-now-ga

Here is an example on how to create a Materialized View:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE MATERIALIZED VIEW schema_name.view_name 
PARTITION BY ... -- the partition column, if used
CLUSTER BY ... -- the partition columns, if used
OPTIONS(labels=[("...", "...")], enable_refresh=true, refresh_interval_minutes=60) -- the options
AS 
SELECT ... 
FROM ...
```

Check the documentation:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/materialized-views-intro